# Oozie Installation error-bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

```
hduser@kas-XX:/usr/lib/Oozie/oozie-4.3.0$ bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests 

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/17/apache-17.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:4.3.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:17 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/17/apache-17.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:4.3.0 (/usr/lib/Oozie/oozie-4.3.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:4.3.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:17 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/17/apache-17.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

Version Information:

```
Hadoop 3.1.2, 

openjdk version "11.0.5" , 

Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.5, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.3.0-26-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix", 

Ubuntu 18.04
```

{personal hadoop environment and single node}

Comment: Hadoop requires Java 8

Comment: `Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/... . Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required`... Did you search this?

Comment: My Mistake..Hadoop is using java8 . openjdk version "11.0.5" is installed version of JAVA on machine90(java -version
).

Comment: And Maven is set to use Java 8 as well?

Comment: repo1.maven.org switched to https only not too long ago. You'll have to update the repository urls in the pom.xml

Comment: After change the https....Command bin/mkdistro.sh [-DskipTests] started but in execution throwing **Waring** and end with **ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed**    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-utils:jar:hadoop-2-4.3.0

Comment: [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:4.3.0, /usr/lib/Oozie/oozie-4.3.0/pom.xml, line 1653, column 21